# integration with angles in spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Is it possible to evaluate the multidimensional integral below, assuming spherical coordinates, without any additional information other than the facts that there is no dependence on $\phi_p$, $\phi_q$, $\phi_{\text w}$, and 
$\{a, b_1, b_2, m, p, q,{\text w},\theta_{\text{ anything}}\}\,>0$ ?

Note that $\theta_{p\,q}$ is the angle between vectors ${\bf p}$ and ${\bf q}$, and similarly for $\theta_{{\text w}\,q}$, $\theta_{p\,{\text w}}\,$; and $|{\bf p}|\,\equiv\,p$ etc.

$\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(\theta_{\text w})\,d{\theta}_{\text w}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\text w}^{2}d{\text w}
\,\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(\theta_{p})d{\theta}_{p}\int_{0}^{\infty}p^{2}d{p}
\,\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(\theta_{q})d{\theta}_{q}\int_{0}^{\infty}q^{2}d{q}\\
\frac{\left[{\text w^{2}}\,+\,m^{2}\right]}{\left[{\text w}^{2}\,+\,a^{2}\right]^{4}\left[{p}^{2}\,+\,a^{2}\right]^{2}\left[{q}^{2}\,+\,b_{2}^{2}\right]^{2}}\cdot\\
\frac{1}{\bigl[p^{2}+q^{2}+{\text w}^{2}-\,2\,p\,q\,\cos(\theta_{p q})+2\,p\,{\text w}\,\cos(\theta_{p {\text w}})-2\,q\,{\text w}\,\cos(\theta_{{\text w} q})+b_{1}^{2}\bigr]}}$

Comment: I myself can’t get anything out of this question, but I think the downvoter owes it to OP to explain the downvote.

Comment: Please note, the original integral to be solved is given by
$\displaystyle{\int {\text d}{\bf q}\,\int {\text d} {\bf p}\, \int {\text d} {\bf w}\,\,
\frac{\left[{\bf w^{2}}\,+\,m^{2}\right]}{\left[{\bf w}^{2}\,+\,a^{2}\right]^{4}\left[{\bf p}^{2}\,+\,a^{2}\right]^{2}\left[{\bf q}^{2}\,+\,b_{2}^{2}\right]^{2}\bigl[({\bf p}-{\bf q}+{\bf w})^{2}+b_{1}^{2}\bigr]^{2}}}$

where ${\bf p}$, ${\bf q}$, ${\bf {\text w}}$ are 3-dimensional vectors. The question asked above is the simplified form of the original integral that is required to be solved.

Comment: Note also that ${\text d}{\bf q}\,=\,{\text d}^{3}q\,$; and similarly for ${\text d}{\bf p}$, ${\text d}{\bf w}$.